# Check whether bytes jpeg is not corrupted jpeg with opencv python

Tags: python, opencv, byte

This `cv2.imdecode` is only giving warning instead of raising error.

```
# Decode the JPEG bytes into a numpy array
frame = np.frombuffer(bytes_jpeg, dtype=np.uint8)

# Decode the JPEG numpy array into a frame
frame = cv2.imdecode(frame, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
```

Even when I check is none by `if frame is None: print('Corrupt')`, it's always not printed. How do I catch `is bytes_jpeg is corrupted jpeg?`

Here is the warnings:

```
Corrupt JPEG data: premature end of data segment
Corrupt JPEG data: premature end of data segment
Corrupt JPEG data: 45342 extraneous bytes before marker 0xd8
Corrupt JPEG data: 17587 extraneous bytes before marker 0xd9
```

Comment: The only thing you'll get from OpenCV is a boolean signalling whether the load failed or succeeded. Anything else is implementation detail. If you want to validate a JPEG, you need to pick a different library that supports such low-level functionality.